# Why is this the earliest date?

Tags: javascript, date

Can you please explain those 2 dates to me? I think first one is ISO 8601 and the other UTC? Is it minus 3 in the first one? So is it actually 8pm? and what is the Z in the second one? what are they in, you know, human language?
Thank you

```
2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00
2020-01-01T00:15:00.000Z
```

Comment: `Z` means zulu time, the time on meridian zero.

Comment: "*I think first one is ISO 8601 and the other UTC*" ISO 8601 is just a date representation format. UTC is a time standard that does not have anything to do with how a date is shown. The two are not mutually exclusive nor in any way competing for the same role.

Answer (score 0):

Both are [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and also [JavaScript's date/time format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) (since JavaScript's format is almost entirely a subset of ISO-8601). The `Z` means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (loosely, GMT — Greenwich Mean Time), it's the equivalent of `+00:00`. The `-03:00` means three hours *before* UTC (for instance, the time zone currently in use in various parts of eastern Brazil such as Brasilia). In human language you might say the first is 11:45 p.m. on New Year's Eve 2019 [BRT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/brt) or "Brasilia time"), and the second one is 15 minutes after midnight New Year's Day [GMT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/gmt) or "UK time" (the UK is on GMT when it's not on British Summer Time, which is GMT+01:00).

To put them in the same time zone, you either add three hours to the first one:

```
2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00 + 3 hours = 2020-01-01T02:45:00.000Z
```

or subtract three hours from the second one.

```
2020-01-01T00:15:00.000Z - 3 hours = 2019-12-31T21:15:00.000-03:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The plus/minus signs on timezones are very confusing, because they've historically been used in opposite ways.

In the case of an ISO-8601 date (like both of those you provided) the minus sign in your first example means three hours *have been subtracted* from UTC in order to display the date as shown, so you should *add* three hours to get UTC.

However, in the current tz database (where timezone designations like "America/Chicago" and "Europe/Paris" come from), one of the ways (albeit older, but still supported) to express the timezone of the date `2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00` is "GMT+3". That naming is based on what *should be added* to get UTC.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. "+0300" designates that "this timestamp is 3 hours ahead of UTC". Going the other way, "UTC is 3 hours behind this place" is not as clear to me. ;-)

Comment: I don't have a preference for one form over the other, I just wish it had gone just one way or the other, and stayed that way.